# Windows Azure website request timeout

Tags: azure, connection-timeout

Our first web app in Azure is having some issues.

From a front end point of view, it is really simple.

It has 2 pages that contain forms the user fills in and click a submit button. This saves the data into Azure table storage.

The problem we are seeing is that the click of the submit button sometimes results in a "connection timeout" error. It is not a massive amount of data that is being submitted, so I don't expect the amount is the issue and it certainly shouldn't take a long time to save.

Initial research into this has brought up [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/a9ff85e8-d039-4091-a0bf-96eeb132b1a0) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx). They both talk about a 1 minute problem and it sounds like what I describe. The second link there has an update in April 2012 saying the 1 minute problem is now resolved and that "default timeout is larger then 1 minute depend on number of current connections".

Does anyone have any further guidance around this area as it appears to be quite sparse on the web (that I can find anyway!). The links talk about background polling to keep your connection alive which seems crazy.

The forms the user are filling in are relatively long and are filled in while they talk to a customer on the phone so can take a while to fill in and submit.

I could have a "heartbeat" async call every 30 seconds or so, but would like to hear what others are doing, or if there is a better way around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the actual underlying technical timeout issues, but for the sanity of your users, I would either break the form down into smaller pages/steps (saving after each step with async), or autosafe (even as a temp record) every 30 seconds. Just so they don't lose work, and have to start over with the customer on the phone.